# What is the best procedure to play SVGA Animation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, svga

i have many Svga Animation which i have to play with in my react native project,  i found react-native-svga-player  using npm i react-native-svga-player but it is not working as it is too old version not getting upgraded with react-native version changed, i use react-native-0.70.3, Please let me know is there any way to play svga Player in react native Project...Please help..

Comment: what kind of error did you get? do you really need 0.70 of react native? probably you enabled new architecture from react native which not many libraries currently support https://reactnative.dev/blog/2022/09/05/version-070

Comment: it even give the error at react-native-0.68.2 and the error is

Comment: Plugin with id 'maven' not found. , then solve it using "apply plugin: 'maven-publish'" at projectfolder/node_modules/react-native-svga-player/android/build.gradle.. then the error comes "A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-svga-player'.
> Configuration with name 'compile' not found." it is solved by using 'customConfig' instead 'compile' at that file  add "configurations {
  customConfig.extendsFrom implementation
}" and then another error comes

Comment: the error comes then 
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-svga-player'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-svga-player:customConfig'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-svga-player
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.3:

Comment: @KirillNovikov any solution to it ? for playing react native svga animation?

Comment: @React_Coder did you find any solution?